# Форма резервации в отель

Tags: php, html

Добрый день есть самописный сайт  отеля ,есть ли какой то модуль для формы резервации а так же что бы заказчик мог сам управлять количеством свободных номеров и тд.
Примерно как тут http://berdshotel.com/ ,как я понял тут оно подключается с сайта https://reservations.travelclick.com/102286?DateIn=03%2F30%2F2018&DateOut=03%2F31%2F2018&Adults=1

Comment: Если сайт самописный без CMS и фреймворков, значит под него ничего готового нету. Или я неправильно понял вопрос?

Comment: Самописаное решение под готовую платформу - это реальность. Готовое под самописную - сказка.

Comment: https://reservations.travelclick.com/103228 что то типа этого